# Align multiple divs to center, without centering the text inside each div tag

Tags: html, css, opencart, centering

I am trying to center the divs inside of a main div, without centering the text inside. it is for a footer sitemap.

How it looks.

[image]

I tried doing it by using**text-align: center** but it centers even my text.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/YU4q6uR.png]

Is there a css rule I have to add?

Comment: Please add your current markup and clarify where you are having the issue. From the image, it looks like you just need to add `text-align: left` for the children of the `text-align: center` container

Comment: Is it OC 2.0 already or still some 1.5.x version?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have something like this:

```
<footer>
    <div>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
    </div>
    <div>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
    </div>
    <div>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
    </div>
    <div>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
         <a href="#">Linky</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And you want the four `div`s to take up equal space? If I understand correctly, just give each div a width of 25% (or adjust for how many divs you have)

Answer (score 0):

Make the divs float:

```
.footer-block {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

the full example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbw4d764/).

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem. You think there is some space at the right-end of the footer, but unfortunately there is none really.

Each list of entries with their h3 title is enclosed in a `<div>` and each of these 4 divs has set a CSS `width: 25%;` - this means that 4 times 25% = 100% of the space => no space left. If you want to push those divs little bit together to create a space around and then center them, you can try something like this:

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer-container">
  <?php if ($informations) { ?>
  <div class="column">
    <h3><?php echo $text_information; ?></h3>
    <ul>
      <?php foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo $information['title']; ?></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="column">
    <h3><?php echo $text_service; ?></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $return; ?>"><?php echo $text_return; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $sitemap; ?>"><?php echo $text_sitemap; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h3><?php echo $text_extra; ?></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>"><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $voucher; ?>"><?php echo $text_voucher; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $affiliate; ?>"><?php echo $text_affiliate; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $special; ?>"><?php echo $text_special; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h3><?php echo $text_account; ?></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $order; ?>"><?php echo $text_order; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $newsletter; ?>"><?php echo $text_newsletter; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

We enclosed all the 4 column divs into another div with id `footer-container` - now let's define some CSS styles for it:

```
#footer-container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now with the smaller width (90%) there is some space around the `#footer-container` and using value `auto` for `margin-left` and `margin-right` should center it inside of the `#footer` div. Feel free to play with the width of `#footer-container` to please your eye.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/my367pfo/) for it.

Notice: this will work fine in 1.5.X versions but may not work properly on the new 2.0 version, since the new 2.0 is build on Bootstrap and uses the grid (columns) system to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a class to the divs that you want to center like this:

```
<div class="middle">Text that goes here</div>
<div class="middle">Text that goes here</div>
<div class="middle">Text that goes here</div>
<div class="middle">Text that goes here</div>
```

Then to center the divs but not the text you write:

```
div.middle{
margin:auto;
text-align:inherit !important;}
```

As you can see I use inherit in text-align because I wan to tell to the browser
"Center the divs with class middle but don't center the text inside that divs"
For more information have a look at this:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp